# histogram on pandas columns by grouping cells

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

l have a column in pandas dataframe called  `Column_values`. l want to make a histogram on these values as follow :

1. Grouping  the cells of  `alphabetic characters`
2. Grouping the cells of  `alpha numeric chacaters`
3. Grouping the cells that contains only `digits and  special chars , ; / .`

Here is my column

```
Column_values
hello
goodmorning
6,35
11,68
Yours
ok
2292
Question
number
those
937,99
and
1
620
amounts
ROB21
Pieces
designation
these
rates
13s
2
with
the
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create the group using a mapping function and then plot the histogram. The function is mapping by condition - in your case:

```
def find_group(val):
    val = str(val)
    if val.isalpha():
        return 'Alpha'
    elif val.isalnum and any(c.isalpha() for c in val):
        return 'Alphanumeric'
    else:
        return 'Special'
```

the transformation is by using pandas apply method:

```
df.Column_values.apply(find_group)
```

and the plotting is by adding value_counts and plot methods:

```
df.Column_values.apply(find_group).value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: what is fun in apply(fun) ? you mean df.Column_values.apply(find_group).value_counts().plot(kind='bar')

Comment: what if we put only val.isalnum() rather than     elif val.isalnum and any(c.isalpha() for c in val):
        return 'Alphanumeric' ?   since isalnum() checks whether it's alphanumeric or not ?

Comment: that might be a problem, since only numbers (f.e. '987') will return True